# Android view crossfading concurency issue

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-animation

In my project I have a lot of asynctask, which all follow this pattern:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    crossfade(progressBar, contentView);//hide content, show progress bar
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    //some work
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
    crossfade(contentView, progressBar);
}
```

Code for crossfade:

```
void crossfade(View contentView, View loadingView){
    Runnable r = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(contentView != null){
                contentView.setAlpha(0f);
                contentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                contentView.animate()
                        .alpha(1f)
                        .setDuration(CROSSFADE_TIME)
                        .setListener(null);

            }
            if(loadingView != null){
                loadingView.animate()
                        .alpha(0f)
                        .setDuration(CROSSFADE_TIME)
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                if(loadingView != null){
                                    loadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }
                        });

            }
        }
    };
    runOnUiThread(r);
}
```

The problem happens when asynctask executes faster than animation time, causing second crossfade call before the first one is finished, resulting in both views being invisible.

I tried queueing runnables to execute them sequentially, but the problem is if user clicks a lot of buttons or many fragments are being loaded(they use crossfade method too), UI thread becomes overloaded and it may crash my app. The only solution I see so far is to add extra delay to all my asynctasks, using Thread.sleep(CROSSFADE_TIME), however it looks like a really dirty hack and I'm not sure if it's a good user experience.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needs it in future, adding loadingView.animate().cancel() and contentView.animate().cancel() before animation cancels previous animations and everything works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you running the crossfade animation in a separate thread? Try to do the animation without 
 `Runnable r = new Runnable(){` and `runOnUiThread(r);`

Comment: It's all called on a main thread, doesn't matter if I call runOnUiThread or call it directly in onPostExecute. I added this line just for convinience, in case I'm calling crossfade in threads other than UI.